# Consulta convertir Int en Fecha - MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

Como puedo realizar una consulta para convertir periodos (YYYYMM) almacenados como INT a fecha (YYYY-MM-DD), pero que la fecha sea siempre el último día del periodo.

Por ejemplo:
202101 resultado esperado >> 2021-01-31 ;
202102 resultado esperado >> 2021-02-28 ;

Comment: convertilo al primer dia del mes, sumale un mes, restale un dia...

Comment: Perfecto, con tu guía pude resolverlo de la siguiente forma: 
SELECT
      DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(PERIODO,'01'),'%Y%m%d'), 
       INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL -1 DAY) as 'FECHA',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un entero a seis dígitos es convertible a fecha, tan sólo multiplica por 100 y tendrás el día cero -que es válido en MySQL- y el resultado lo pasas a la función `last_day()` para obtener el último día del mes:

```
last_day(202102*100)
```

Resulta

```
2021-02-28
```